# I want allow only list of wallets to mint NFTs without token airdrop ,How do i do it on Sugar Candy Machine

Tags: web3.js, nft, candymachine

I want allow only list of wallets to mint NFTs without token airdrop ,How do i do it on Sugar Candy Machine

I have to pass list of wallets that only can mint NFTs can you share how do i write on config fil